# How to set readonly property in extension?

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I need to simulate loadScores request on GKLeaderboard.
For that i've created extension:

```
extension GKLeaderboard {
    func testLoadScores(completion: @escaping ([GKScore]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        ...
        self.maxRange = 100
    }
}
```

But is says

> Cannot assign to property: 'maxRange' is a get-only property

So how i can override this property?
Link to description of property: [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/1503136-maxrange)

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar maxRange is embeded property by Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the issue is that `maxRange` property is set automatically when `loadScores(completionHandler:)` is completed and you should not try to set it on your own

[maxRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/1503136-maxrange)

> This property is invalid until a call to loadScores(completionHandler:) is completed. Afterward, it contains the total number of entries available to return to your game given the filters you applied to the query.

I suppose you should use `range` to get (filter) top N scores

[range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboard/1503144-range)

> The range property is ignored if the leaderboard request was initialized using the init(playerIDs:) method. Otherwise, the range property is used to filter which scores are returned to your game. For example, if you specified a range of [1,10], after the search is complete, your game receives the best ten scores. The default range is [1,25].
>   The minimum index is 1. The maximum length is 100.

**OR:** If you want to get all the scores and there're more than 100 of them it seems you should recursively load scores with increasing ranges, like [1,100], [101,200] ... [1101, 1200].. and so on till you get a range with less than 100 scores. But implementing paging is a better idea because it's possible there are so many scores that they will take too much time to load them all